# Vim function to switch between splits

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to find a function which will switch back to the original window in a split view for vim. I know about  shortcut and I also know about the function :call cursor. But is there a function which can let me switch back to the previous split window so I could stick it in my vim function?

Comment: Also for questions about Vim and Vi one could be interested in the [dedicated stack exchange site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @statox thanks I didn't know about it. Bookmarked!!

Comment: Why a function when there's `<C-w>p`?

Comment: @romainl so I can use it in a script. I didn't know how to use a shortcut in vim script

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a vimscript you can use:

```
" Save the window where you are currently
let l:currentWindow=winnr()

" Do stuff where you change of window

" Go back to the original window
exe l:currentWindow . "wincmd w"
```

For more information the doc is always an excellent reading:

- [`:h wincmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:wincmd)
- [`:h winnr()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#winnr())

**Edit** Another way to do it is to use `wincmd p`:

`wincmd` is the vimscript equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> in normal mode.

In normal mode when you change of window you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> to come back to the previous window. So in vimscript you simply use:

```
wincmd p
```

To go back to the previous window.

Of course if the rest of your function use more than 2 splits you will not go back to your initial window but if you have only two splits it can be lighter than using a variable to keep the number of your window.

Comment: May I ask how you found it?

Comment: Is there a similar function which checks if there is split already present? then instead of creating a new split I can just switch into the other window and do the stuff...

Comment: @SUB For the "how I found it" I was trying to find a way to use `windo` without changing the current window from the user point of view so I read [`:h window`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window) and worked with Vimscript... For your second question you should read [`:h winnr()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#winnr()). Knowing that `winnr('$')` gives you the total number of splits in the current tab you should be able to work with it.

Comment: I am on vim 6.4 The function winnr('$') doesn't work. Is there something old school for finding the number of split windows?

Comment: @SUB upgrade... (Vim 6.4 came out almost 10 years ago)